# JavaScript alert code does not display any message

Tags: javascript

I have a simple js code witch should alert if `allbought` is `true`, but nothing happens. It just logs "win" in the console, but won't alert. I also tried `window.alert` but that won't work either.

```js
let money = 0;
let allbought = false

function clicked() {
  let rewardSound = new Audio('../media/reward.mp3');
  rewardSound.volume = 0.2;
  rewardSound.play();
  money = money + 10000000000;
  document.getElementById("yourmoney").innerHTML = `<h3>Pénzed: ${money}</h3>`
  console.log(money)
}


function bought() {
  if (glassesbought == true && glockbought == true && kesbought == true && m5e60bought == true && amgonebought == true && dogbought == true && garazsbought == true && lifebought == true && gnihazbought == true) {
    allbought = true
    console.log(allbought)
  }
}

function win() {
  if (allbought == true) {
    console.log('win')
    alert("hello")
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="buy-grid footer">
  <article id="szemuveg" class="buyable szemuvegbg" onclick="szemuveg(); bought(); win();">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 1%;">Napszemüveg</h4><br>
    <p style="margin-top: -10%; margin-left: 1%;">Ha menő vagy éjjel is hordod.<br> Ár:100.000</p>
  </article>
  <article id="glock" class="buyable glockbg" onclick="glock(); bought(); win();">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 1%;">Glock</h4><br>
    <p style="margin-top: -10%; margin-left: 1%;">Nem mered nem bejelenteni.<br>Ár:300.000</p>
    </h4>
  </article>
  <article id="kes" class="buyable kesbg" onclick="kes(); bought(); win();">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 1%;">Kés</h4><br>
    <p style="margin-top: -10%; margin-left: 1%;">"Ez nem tőr, ez gyroszoskard!"<br>Ár:200.000</p>
    </h4>
  </article>
  <article id="m5e60" class="buyable m5e60bg" onclick="m5e60(); bought(); win();">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 1%;">BMW M5 e60</h4><br>
    <p style="margin-top: -10%; margin-left: 1%;">Kötelező kellék<br>Ár:2.200.000</p>
  </article>
  <article id="amgone" class="buyable amgonebg" onclick="amgone(); bought(); win();">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 1%;">AMG One</h4><br>
    <p style="margin-top: -10%; margin-left: 1%;">Ritka, és kurva drága. <br> Kihagyhatatlan. <br> Ár:5.000.000$</p>
  </article>
  <article id="dog" class="buyable dogbg" onclick="dog(); bought(); win();">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 1%;">Kutya</h4><br>
    <p style="margin-top: -10%; margin-left: 1%;">Olyan mint te<br>Ár:1.000.000</p>
    </h4>
  </article>
  <article id="garazs" class="buyable garazsbg" onclick="garazs(); bought(); win();">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 1%;">Nagy garázs</h4><br>
    <p style="margin-top: -10%; margin-left: 1%;">Nagy de nem eléggé.<br> Ár:1.500.000</p>
  </article>
  <article id="life" class="buyable lifebg" onclick="life(); bought(); win();">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 1%;">Élet</h4><br>
    <p style="margin-top: -10%; margin-left: 1%;">Nem árt ha van.<br> Ár:10.000.000</p>
  </article>
  <article id="gnihaz" class="buyable grid-col-span2 gnihazbg" onclick="gnihaz(); bought(); win();">
    <h4 style="margin-left: 1%;">GNI ház</h4><br>
    <p>Mindenki tudja, hogy a legnagyobb gangsterek itt laknak. <br>Ár:6.000.000</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Where is `allbought` defined? How do you call the function?

Comment: Please provide the code that is necessary to *reproduce* the issue.

Comment: Try to reset the site settings, perhaps you prevented the site from showing alerts

Comment: I updated the original post with more code, and I didn't prevent the site from showing alerts. Also I tried 3 browsers.(opera, firefox and edge)

Comment: you have a lot of buttons to debug. Please pick a scenario, explain what you do, what you expect and what actually happens. For now, if I press those buttons, I get errors like "szemuveg is not a function" since you omitted those functions. Remove the other code that's not needed to reproduce the issue (see [mcve]). Try to debug yourself and ask a more specific question. Best regards

Comment: You have a lot of obsolete `</h4>` closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

You've named a local function "alert". So after it logs 'win' the next line which calls 'alert' will actually call your local method.

So I would either rename your local alert method or use window.alert instead. Or probably what you want is to add a line for window.alert inside your local alert method.

Comment: renaming the function did't  fix it.

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function win(allbought){
    if(allbought == true){
        console.log('win')
        alert("hello");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="win(true);">Click Here</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It still won't work. :(